# how to have a file in the root of the android apk generated by unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a file eula.zip which I want to be in root of the android apk when i build from unity3d.

in unity 4.0 I can do this by exporting as android project and pasting the zip file in
android project root and then building apk from eclipse

but I have to do it in unity3.5,
I have tried to place it in following locations-
Assets folder
plugins folder
Plugins/Android folder
none of these seam to work

what should do to have eula.zip in the root of the android apk from unity.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is quite old, but it still shows up in the Google search and I found an elegant solution:

Simply copy the files directly into your project's src directory (not into the com.whatever... package).

Answer (score 0):

try modify this directory:

C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer

or

C:\Program Files(x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer

Comment: i tried what you said and pasted "eula.zip" in the "AndroidPlayer" folder but it is still not present in the root of the apk after building from unity. infact it is not present any where in the apk. and I also pasted it in "AndroidDevelopmentPlayer"

Comment: what 'root of the android apk' mean, that's impossible, only classes.dex and AndroidManifest.xml will be in root of android apk. put zip file in AndroidPlayer/assets as android asset resource, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you're looking for the "file:///android_asset/" directory, in the eclipse project it would be in the /assets subdirectory.

in unity, use this:

Plugins/Android/assets

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, it is more a hack, rather than a good way to solve the issue.
I have made it this way:

1. Decompile the apk with apktool
2. Add file to needed directory of decompiled project
3. Make sure apktool.yml includes your file when compiling apk
4. Compile project
5. Sign obtained apk with jarsigner